# How to check if the element is present while parsing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XDocument new_doc which has the following XML like

```
<lab:lab uri="https://bh03.org/api/lb/3" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:lab="http://ge.com/ri/lab">
<name>GTech</name>
<udf:field type="String" name="Account ID">gt</udf:field>
</lab:lab>
```

With the below code I am trying to get the Value for Account ID

```
   XNamespace ns = "http://ge.com/ri/userdefined";
   accountID = new_doc.Descendants(ns + "field").FirstOrDefault(field => field.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Account ID")).Value;
```

But how do I check if the `<udf:field type="String" name="Account ID">gt</udf:field>` is present before getting the value for the Account ID. Because sometimes the XML might be something like below

```
  <lab:lab uri="https://bh03.org/api/lb/3" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:lab="http://ge.com/ri/lab">
  <name>GTech</name>
  </lab:lab>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath and check if *field* is null or not..

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("udf", "http://ge.com/ri/userdefined");
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);  

var field = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//udf:field[@name]", nsmgr);
if(field != null)
{
    var name = field.Attribute("name");
}
```

PS: In fact `//udf:field` is enough. `//udf:field[@name]` checks also the existence of *name* attribute. A more restricted version of it can be `//udf:field[@name='Account ID']`

Comment: what is the filename here

Comment: @trx your xml file. If you have your xml as string you can use *XDocument.Parse*